# Futures in nHibernate Linq

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, membership-provider, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm interested on solution how to use Futures in counting something having Linq in mind. I'm not interested in Criteria api, just plain linq.

If I have:

```
IEnumerable<User> dbUsers = userquery.Future<User>(); 
IFutureValue<long> count = totalcountQuery.FutureValue<long>();
```

direct translation should be:

```
var dbUsers = userQuery.ToFuture();     
var count = userQuery.LongCount();
```

**Now I need to access count query to know exact number of populated records;**

something like this, although this code wont compile:

```
totalRecords = (int)count.Value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly supported by NHibernate, but it is very easy to implement (explained in this [blog post](http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2011/02/getting-row-count-with-future-linq.html)). You need to write a new extension method.

```
public static IFutureValue<TResult> ToFutureValue<TSource, TResult>
    (this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<IQueryable<TSource>, TResult>> selector)
    where TResult:struct  where TSource: class
{
    var provider = (INhQueryProvider) source.Provider;
    var method = ((MethodCallExpression) selector.Body).Method;
    var expression = Expression.Call(null, method, source.Expression);
    return (IFutureValue<TResult>) provider.ExecuteFuture(expression);
}
```

Then it is easy to get a paged query

```
var query = session.Query<User>().Where(...);
var count = query.ToFutureValue(u => u.Count());
var results = query.OrderBy(u => u.FullName).Skip(n).Take(m).ToFuture()
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
var users = Session.Query<User>().ToFuture();
var totalCount = users.Count();
```